# Delphi 11 Alexandria LSP code completion problem

Tags: delphi, code-completion, delphi-11-alexandria

Is there any way to solve the problem when you add a new unit to a project and LSP Code Completion doesn't recognize the new functions/procedures? Sometimes I have to close and reopen the IDE for it to recognize them.

I have a project with more than 300 units, and sometimes it doesn't recognize `uses` that I add, and I try to use functions or procedures. It only works if I close the IDE.

I don't have such problems in Delphi 10.3.

Comment: Embarcadero's LSP is "Language Server Protocol", not the tag you used. You're better off posting to the bug tracker.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the IDE. [File a bug report with Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to a brand new unit that does not yet exist on disk, then that is a known limitation of Code Completion.  Once the unit has been saved to disk, then it should work as expected.

I believe this was stated in the launch webinar by David Millington and is referenced in the "Items to be aware of" section of a RAD Studio 11 wiki page.
https://github.com/ideasawakened/DelphiKB/wiki/D28.ALEXANDRIA.11.1.0.0

Comment: file exists on disk and added to currenty project, so, code completion dont recognize, i have wich close and reopen project or ide for works. I have. 
same which not have any errors on my sources